# iterating NSArray, checking items?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have an NSArray collection. it contains NSArray and NSDictionary.
while i iterate the items i want to check if it is NSArray or NSDictionary.

```
for (int i=0;i<[data count];i++){
[data objectAtIndex:i]// how can i check 
}
```

any help, please???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id obj = [data objectAtIndex:i];
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
   //...
} else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't use `for`, there's a great `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method.

Comment: enumerateObjectsWithBlock? how can i use it?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use array indices in your `for` loop, but there's usually no reason to prefer `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` over the syntactically much simpler `for (id obj in array) {...}`.

Comment: `[data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { ...your code here... }];`

Comment: @KyrDunenkoff Unless you already have a block (e.g. one that you get from some API or that you want to reuse), this has no real benefit over a simple for-in loop and it introduces some memory management implications (like `__block` variables) that potentially make this method harder to use for a beginner.

Comment: Well, it took me half a year to understand blocks. Better start early.

Comment: i will try block too. for loop is enough now. thanks both of you.